# Holding Sefer Torah during Hoshanos and Walking Around Bima with Lulav

Tags: halacha, synagogue, hoshana-rabbah, hoshanos

This morning I saw the person holding the sefer Torah at the Bimah during Hoshanos pass the Torah to another person for a short time so he could walk around the Bimah with his lulav and Esrog.

I never saw such behavior in the past; the sefer Torah holder simply did not walk around during Hoshanos since he was preoccupied with another minhag  / mitzva of holding the Torah during Hoashanos.

I would expect that passing the Torah to another might even be prohibited because of "ain ma'avirin al hamitzvos" one may not pass over a mitzva that is closer and certainly not one which one is actively involved. (See Kesef Mishna Hilchos Sefer Torah 10,6 that holding a Torah is a mitzvah)

Is there any discussion on this matter in the halachik literature?

Comment: Is holding the Torah a mitzvah? Which?

Comment: @DoubleAA Holding Torah is a minhag and observing minhagim is a mitzva of al titosh or as Rashba and others write "minhag yisroel Torah" ...but anyway see Kesef Mishna Hilchos Sefer Torah 10,6 that holding a Torah is a mitzvah

Comment: So how do people pass Torahs on simchas torah? Also, I've never heard of holding torahs being a minhag.

Comment: @DoubleAA Because they are not passing the Torah to do another mitzvah; they are passing it because someone else also wants to get the mitzva of dancing with the Torah or they can't hold it any longer.

In your shul they don't take out the Torah during Hashnaos? I think it is a near universal minhag